# MongoDb crashed with warning: can't move chunk of size (approximately) 20337144 because maximum size allowed to move is 67108864

Tags: mongodb, sharding

we have been using MongoDB of 2.4.4 version

after the warning mongos crahes with:

> warning: problem while initially checking shard versions on [replica name]
>   error loading initial database config information :: caused by
>   :: Couldn't load a valid config for [collection]

chunks for this collection:

```
use config
db.chunks.find({ns:'<collection name>'})
```

I found invalid chunk, something like:

```
/* 2 */
{
...
    "min" : {
        "a" : NumberLong(10)
    },
    "max" : {
        "a" : NumberLong(20)
    },
...
}
/* 3 */
{
...
    "min" : {
        "a" : NumberLong(20)
    },
    "max" : {
        "a" : NumberLong(30)
    },
...
}
/* 4 */
{
...
    "min" : {
        "a" : NumberLong(-9190751889607709064)
    },
    "max" : {
        "a" : NumberLong(91892557)
    },
...

/* 5 */
{
...
    "min" : {
        "a" : NumberLong(30)
    },
    "max" : {
        "a" : NumberLong(40)
    },
...
}
```

it is easy to guess that chunk /* 4 */ is invalid :)
Mongo works normally, after delete the chunk.

How to resolve the issue?
I've found bug in mongo which probably is the reason: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11943
but it is fixed only in unstable 2.7.2 version.
Do you have any ideas how to fix it in the current stable mongoDb releases?

Comment: Di you try splitting this chink?

Comment: No, I didn't try. As I know, MongoDB splits chunks automatically in normal cases

Comment: Yes, but your case is not normal :). You could try manually splitting. These link should help: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/split/#dbcmd.split  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/split-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/

Comment: I already deleted invalid chunk and I can't try this :) It was critical for me to restore mongodb as soon as possible. And now I want to prevent same crashes in future

Comment: You could basically keep pre-splitted chunks if you know the ranges well, this will make sure that you don't end up with JUMBO chunks.

Comment: SERVER-11943 explains the poor error message but not why chunk 4 became invalid. Something got messed up in the cluster metadata, which is what the first message from mongos says, but if you've deleted the chunk and moved on we probably won't be able to tell why. Hopefully it will work well in the future.